# Circle radius not being sized correctly

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

my script isn't working. It was supposed to create random circles all touching the bottom of the canvas, with their radius shrinking each circle by the number of circles.

Here is the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++){
   var circle = new Circle(radius);
   circle.setPosition(CENTER_X,CENTER_Y);
   circle.setColor(color);
   add(circle);
    
   radius /= i;
   CENTER_Y = getHeight() - radius;
   color = Randomizer.nextColor();
}
```

Comment: show full runnnable code

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the full code:

```
var NUM_CIRCLES = 30;
var BIG_RADIUS = 180;
var color = Randomizer.nextColor();
var radius = BIG_RADIUS;
var CENTER_X = getWidth() / 2;
var CENTER_Y = getHeight() - radius;

function start(){
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++){
        var circle = new Circle(radius);
        circle.setPosition(CENTER_X,CENTER_Y);
        circle.setColor(color);
        add(circle);
    
        radius /= i;
        CENTER_Y = getHeight() - radius;
        color = Randomizer.nextColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that is not full code... and you should add that to the question not as an answer ... what library are you using?

Answer (score -1):

as far as i understand you are trying to produce circles from bigger to smaller reducing radius of them by number of circles

to achive that do `eachReduce = radius / numberofcircles` and use it as eachReduce constant to reduce each circle by that number to achieve bigger to smaller size till zero
take a look at below example

```js
let numofcir = 10,
    radius = 80,
    reduceEachBy = radius / numofcir,
    offset = radius / 2

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 360);
  noLoop()
}

function draw() {
  background(0)
  stroke(255)
  noFill()

  for(let i=0;i < numofcir;i++){
    // in p5 ellipse creates circle by x and y radius
    ellipse(offset + (i * offset),150,radius,radius)
    radius -= reduceEachBy
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4kV7GkNv7QR7RX9YF/olywyIgIwNvfEe2nZtfyj73HdjCUkAfOBDbcuJ/cTaN04JKRnw1YG1wnUyNKMsNgg3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Ok, give me one second

Comment: var NUM_CIRCLES = 30;
var BIG_RADIUS = 180;
var color = Randomizer.nextColor();
var radius = BIG_RADIUS;
var CENTER_X = getWidth() / 2;
var CENTER_Y = getHeight() - radius;

function start(){

    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++){
        var circle = new Circle(radius);
        circle.setPosition(CENTER_X,CENTER_Y);
        circle.setColor(color);
        add(circle);
        
        radius /= i;
        CENTER_Y = getHeight() - radius;
        color = Randomizer.nextColor();
    }
}

Comment: Why didn't that work?

Comment: no runnable code is only supported in question or answer box not work in comments

Comment: see updated ans

Comment: take a look at updated ans does that helps in anyway ?

Comment: if this solves your problem consider accepting answer or if not then explain problem further

Comment: @AmirRahman how do you know that he is using P5.js?  there is no indication he is using that on his question

Comment: i just used p5 to show the idea of making circles from bigger to smaller that he can implement in his code i used p5 just to show a demo since his version of code need dependencies which cannot be run here so i made a separate version to illustrate